# M2Mqtt.NET-The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm

Tags: asp.net, mqtt, tls1.2, mosquitto, aws-iot

I'm using **[M2Mqtt.NET](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.m2mqtt/)** to connect to a `AWS IoT broker`. When I try to connect, the exception `The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm` occurs.

**Code:**

```
//getting certificates from file
X509Certificate certRoot = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("path/to/root.crt");
X509Certificate certClient = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("path/to/client.crt");

//creating client
var mqttClient = new MqttClient("brokerAddress",
                                    8883,
                                    true,
                                    new X509Certificate(certRoot),
                                    new X509Certificate(certClient),
                                    MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2);

//connecting client-the problem line
mqttClient.Connect(AppConstants.CLIENT_ID); //GUID
```

**Things I tried:**

- Checked and confirmed that server is running `TLS 1.2`
- Installed both certificates as trusted
- Creating new certificates
- Using certificates through `Resources` file
- Running web project on HTTPS

**Project Setup:**

- ASP.NET MVC Project
- .NET 4.5.2
- Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit (10.0, Build 10240)

Comment: Have you tried using something like wireshark to capture the TLS handshake to see what the client/broker are offering as algorithms? It may also be useful to share your mosquitto.conf

Comment: @hardillb: I'm trying to connect to `AWS IoT Broker` and it hasn't provided any kind of `config` file. Both of the are generated by `AWS`

Comment: The first line of your question said you were using mosquitto, please edit the question to reflect what you are actually doing

Comment: @hardillb: updated. can you provide any help to `AWS IoT` or why this is happening?